# Unable to retrieve a value of custom added column in tier prices?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, overrides, resource-model, tierprice

I have added a new column 'tier_type' in table catalog_product_entity_tier_price i am able to save and edit it's value but this value is not getting retrieved in both the admin panel and front end.

Files content :

**Config.xml**

```
<config>

    <modules>
       <Companyname_Catalog>
     <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Companyname_Catalog>
    </modules>       
    <global>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_type_price>Companyname_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price</product_type_price>
                <product_attribute_backend_tierprice>Companyname_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Tierprice</product_attribute_backend_tierprice>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>                            
        <catalog_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <product_attribute_backend_tierprice>Companyname_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Attribute_Backend_Tierprice</product_attribute_backend_tierprice>
            </rewrite>                            
        </catalog_resource>
    </models>
    </global>

</config>
```

In app/code/local/Companyname/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Attribute/Backend/Tierprice.php

```
<?php 

class Companyname_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Attribute_Backend_Tierprice extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Attribute_Backend_Tierprice

{

public function loadProductPrices($product, $attribute)
    {
    //add new column name to the sql
    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
        ->from($this>getMainTable(), array(
            'website_id', 'all_groups', 'cust_group' => 'customer_group_id',
            'price_qty' => 'qty', 'price' => 'value', 'tier_type',
        ))
        ->where('entity_id=?', $product->getId())
        ->order('qty');
    if ($attribute->isScopeGlobal()) {
        $select->where('website_id=?', 0);
    }
    else {
        if ($storeId = $product->getStoreId()) {
            $select->where('website_id IN (?)', array(0, Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId()));
        }
    }
    return $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
    }
}

?>
```

Please answer if any one have been through this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I gather you confirmed the value is indeed saved into the DB? What is the actual SQL that gets created in the method above? `echo $select;` will produce the actual SQL query used. Take that SQL and use it in a sql client to see what results you get. Generally having a look at the underlying SQL will give you a clue as to why your data is not returning.

Comment: echo $select not showing anything even die() isn't working here .

Comment: Try echo (string) $select

Comment: SO, what was the result of this, or did you just give up on all of this?

Comment: Hello ProxiBlue i have solved it and will post the solution as an answer here asap. thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi Sarvagya, can you please share your solution here.. i am stuck with same problem.